# Why SpringMVC4.2.5 call twice Controller when run RequestMappingHandlerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am sure that http request just send once.But when deal function  `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal`, it is obviously call twice `invokeHandlerMethod`.The Code:

```
@Override
protected ModelAndView handleInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) throws Exception {

    ModelAndView mav = null;
    checkRequest(request);

    // Execute invokeHandlerMethod in synchronized block if required.
    if (this.synchronizeOnSession) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            Object mutex = WebUtils.getSessionMutex(session);
            synchronized (mutex) {
                mav = invokeHandlerMethod(request, response, handlerMethod);
            }
        }
    }

    mav = invokeHandlerMethod(request, response, handlerMethod);

    if (getSessionAttributesHandler(handlerMethod).hasSessionAttributes()) {
        applyCacheSeconds(response, this.cacheSecondsForSessionAttributeHandlers);
    }
    else {
        prepareResponse(response);
    }

    return mav;
}
```

I can't understand why call twice `invokeHandlerMethod(request, response, handlerMethod)` in here.That `mav` must be the result of second invoke anyway, right?

Comment: I have read the version 4.2.4 and that version before, none of that use this process.I think this would be a bug of springwebmvc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely a high severity defect. It looks like they already fixed it here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/a02fd7c9953b8e7f629f4d3a66a450a13341576b#diff-c10711e48b26eaecfb5aec8e59afb678

Comment: I has reduced my webmvc version to 4.2.4.But you helped me a lot.Thank you  very much.